# PHP Mail Showing Error "unexpected_data_after_address@.syntax-error"

Tags: php, mysql

i write php Code for sending mail

```
$to = $sql_sender_final['email'];
$from = "first+$form[2]+$form[1]+$conversion@example.in<first@example.in>";

$headers = "From: $from\n";

$subject = "Re:New Message";
$message =  $body_new;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

then I Write a code for fetching data from mail "first@example.in" through IMAP

all other fetched data Showing well Except to it showing Error Like this

( ! ) Notice: Unknown: Unexpected characters at end of address: <abc@example
.in> (errflg=3) in Unknown on line 0

( ! ) Notice: Unknown: Unexpected characters at end of address: <def@example.in> (errflg=3) in Unknown on line 0

I study lot about this error on google but I Can't succeed

Comment: 1. Escape your variables.
2. the string concatenation operator in PHP is the dot (.) operator
3. Show what you want the actual header to look like

Comment: Start by finding out what your variables contain. That's something we cannot do for your. A simple [var_dump()](http://php.net/var_dump) will do.

Comment: My Error Ispublic 'to' => 
    array (size=2)
      'abc+u211+u210+677f79a63acf35c47ba7d6b7d21b7ae1d9de93d2@def.in' => null
      'unexpected_data_after_address@.syntax-error.' => null

Comment: A comma will also cause this error. For example "From: ABC Electric, Inc. <mail@abc.co>" will fail, whereas "From: ABC Electric Inc. <mail@abc.co>" will succeed. Per the spec (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) that states: "The from field consists of the field name "From" and a comma-separated list of one or more mailbox specifications."

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem too, I think it happens only if displayed name is in email format along with email: `some@ema.il <some@ema.il>`. I am using `php-imap/php-imap` package, which internally uses `imap_*` PHP functions, so probably it's low-level bug (feature?).

I just do the filtering after message parsing and log IMAP errors:

```
/* @var $mailbox \PhpImap\Mailbox */
$mail = $mailbox->getMail($msgId, false);

// This will handle IMAP errors and will not trigger PHP notice
// You can log it somewhere in your own way.
$imapErrors = array_unique(array_filter(array_merge(
    (array) imap_errors(),
    (array) imap_alerts()
)));
```

And then `$mail->getTo()`, `$mail->getCc()` can be filtered with something like this:

```
function filterValidEmails(array $emails)
{
    $validEmails = [];

    foreach ($emails as $email => $name) {
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $validEmails[$email] = $name;
        }
    }

    return $validEmails;
}
```